# How to optimize "don't care" argument with gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

Sometimes a function doesn't use an argument (perhaps because another "flags" argument doesn't enable a specific feature).

However, you have to specify something, so usually you just put `0`. But if you do that, and the function is external, `gcc` will emit code to "really make sure" that parameter gets set to `0`.

Is there a way to tell `gcc` that a particular argument to a function doesn't matter and it can leave alone whatever value it is that happens to be in the argument register right then?

**Update:** Someone asked about the XY problem. The context behind this question is I want to implement a varargs function in `x86_64` without using the compiler varargs support. This is simplest when the parameters are on the stack, so I declare my functions to take 5 or 6 dummy parameters first, so that the last non-vararg parameter and all of the vararg parameters end up on the stack. This works fine, except it's clearly not optimal - when looking at the assembly code it's clear that `gcc` is initializing all those argument registers to zero in the caller.

Comment: If the function is "external" (i.e. is defined in another [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29)) then no there's really no way to omit passing the argument. Can you please elaborate on why you want this kind of micro-optimization? What is the *actual* and *original* problem you want to solve with this? Please [read about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sure, in principle, you have to pass an argument, but if it is a register argument then passing it is `O(0)` if you just leave it uninitialized which is the goal of this question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Added XY problem support to the question.

Comment: Why do you want to implement a varargs function without `<stdarg.h>`?  It is not guaranteed to work.   You get into problems like this.  Don't do it.  It is retrograde, 70s-era coding to do this.  If you want to do it, get a compiler from that era — they don't complain.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It *is* guaranteed to work under reasonable assumptions (System V calling convention). Why should I care about the whiz-double-bang compatibility of my program when I only run Linux and maybe planning to one day use OpenBSD which also uses the System V calling convention?

Comment: It depends on your definition of 'guaranteed'.  The C standard certainly doesn't guarantee it.  Neither does GCC.  System V is about 30 years old — maybe a bit older.  Using it as 'reasonable assumptions' is not necessarily sensible.  And modern compilers generally don't do things the way you expect; they take the utmost delight in optimizing the programmer's faulty assumptions into code that doesn't work.  And you've still not explained why you think it would be a good idea to avoid using the `<stdarg.h>` mechanism.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, the 64-bit CC isn't quite 30 years old yet. But the point is it's being used right now, it's the default CC supported by gcc, it's an industry standard backed by both major x86_64 hardware vendors (although the processors are supposed to be CC agnostic). Ultimately I don't think it's going away anytime soon.

Comment: I don't understand what you're claiming. Suffice to say, I think you are headed in the wrong direction and will run into problems sooner or later.  Do as you wish. You can't say you weren't warned.  I trust the code isn't mission critical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137806/discussion-between-depresseddaniel-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't take below answer seriously. The question asks for a hack so there you go.

GCC will effectively treat value of uninitialized variable as "don't care" so we can try exploiting this:

```
int foo(int x, int y);

int bar_1(int y) {
  int tmp = tmp;  // Suppress uninitialized warnings
  return foo(tmp, y);
}
```

Unfortunately my version of GCC still cowardly initializes `tmp` to zero but yours may be more aggressive:

```
bar_1:
.LFB0:
  .cfi_startproc
  movl  %edi, %esi
  xorl  %edi, %edi
  jmp   foo
  .cfi_endproc
```

Another option is (ab)using inline assembly to fake GCC into thinking that `tmp` is defined (when in fact it isn't):

```
int bar_2(int y) {
  int tmp;
  asm("" : "=r"(tmp));
  return foo(tmp, y);
}
```

With this GCC managed to get rid of parameter initializations:

```
bar_2:
.LFB1:
  .cfi_startproc
  movl  %edi, %esi
  jmp   foo
  .cfi_endproc
```

Note that inline asm must be immediately before the function call, otherwise GCC will think it has to preserve output values which would harm register allocation.

Comment: Brilliant! I'm going to go with the `asm` option as it's easy enough to stuff in a preprocessor macro. While hacky it's also perfectly safe - absent a bug in `gcc` inline `asm` those statements ought to be harmless wherever they may occur.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel Right, shouldn't fail modulo compiler bugs.